# Filter server names with specific permissions (Discord API)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm using the Discord API to get all the guilds the user is in. With the JSON response, I'm trying to filter out all the server names where the user has the manage_guild permission with list comprehension.

`all_guild_names = [x['name'] for x in guilds if int(x['permissions']) & 0x00000020 != 0]`
guilds is the name of the json response. 'name' and 'permissions' are keys in guilds.

This code doesn't give any errors but it returns an empty list. I want it to return a list of the names of the guilds that has the manage_guild permission. Does anyone know how to do this or how to do it in another way?

Example JSON Response:

```
user 1 JSON response:
[
 {
 "id": "333",
 "name": "hello"
 "permissions": "0"
 },
 {
 "id": "999",
 "name": "hi"
 "permissions": "1"
 },
 {
 "id": "666",
 "name": "abc"
 "permissions": "2"
 },
]

user 2 JSON response:
[
 {
 "id": "555",
 "name": "hello"
 "permissions": "10"
 },
 {
 "id": "1001",
 "name": "hi"
 "permissions": "6"
 },
 {
 "id": "26236",
 "name": "abc"
 "permissions": "20"
 },
]
```

The JSON response will be different for each user. That's why I'm using list comprehension to try and search for the value.

Comment: Could you add an example of json data that you are using as input to this code?

Comment: I just added the JSON response to the question.

Comment: There is no `permissions` key in the json response that you posted. The code works fine for me when I use a permissions key. Could you check if the condition that you are using for filtering is correct?

Comment: that's just an example JSON response. The actual response is lengthy. The JSON is structured the same way as in the example. When I did the code, it would just return an empty list when It should be returning a list of names.

Comment: I just tried the code again and it doesn't return an empty list. I'm not sure what happened last time. Thanks for your time.